# RFID tag sensitivity

Tags: rfid

I have an RFID simulation that has an antenna, which generated power is 2 mT in a certain range.

If an RFID tag has a sensitivity of -10 dBm, can I use that information to evaluate if the tag will be powered on for example in the range where the magnetic field is 2 mT?

Comment: A bar magnet can outstrip a coil with a few dozen amps in terms of flux density (mT or milli tesla) but it can't ever (not ever) power up an RFID tag. So, do you see the problem here? Telling us the mT tells us nothing.

Comment: @Andyaka Okey, I read that in low frequency RFID systems, the tag generates it's power from the electromagnetic pulse generated by the antenna coil. I'm using COMSOL multiphysics as my simulation model. So what values I should examine generated from the antenna?